# Electrolux Induction Stove Board IC bricked and 1 Resistor too

Tags: integrated-circuit

An integrated circuit has blown and how can I workaround that. Can I install other similar looking IC or also maybe directly solder some wires somehow to make the board circuit close.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It isn't clear what the ``and 1 Resistor too`` part of the question title refers to. The question text doesn't mention a resistor, and from the picture can't see any obvious damage to a resistor.

Comment: The Resistor component cannot be seen in this picture. it is extending top-right part of the picture

Comment: Can't edit my post due to Spam?? . Anyways, a name for the IC or a link to purchase it is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture, the board is AC-DC power supply, which converts 120-230 AC voltage into some lower DC voltage using an transformer and a high-voltage controller IC that drives some high-voltage MOSFET. You cannot replace the 8-pin IC with "similar-looking" IC, because the burned IC has a very specific function.

As a matter of fact, even if you replace the IC with exactly the same kind, it is VERY likely that it will go into smoke the moment you apply AC voltage. This is because the problem in this circuit is likely in a failure of some other component of this circuit, it could be the power FET, or break in isolation inside the transformer, or one of caps went out of initial parameters, or optical isolator went bad, or rectifier bridge. The only solution (at your level of understanding) is to find a replacement for the entire board.

Comment: Mentioned Resistor (Gold, Red, Green, Yellow) has continuity. I understand very clear what you said. Very cool. Also another scenario is the continuity of this Resistor has cause all that trouble. What are the chances of a Resistor fusing into a single segment and causing this continuity. Probably very very rare.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I install other similar looking IC or also maybe directly solder some wires somehow to make the board circuit close.

The circuit isn't permanently closed. It closes and opens at a rate of several 10s of kHz, and the closing and opening periods are not arbitrary but are controlled by the chip. The circuit is a switching power supply. If the switch is permanently closed with a wire, the primary transformer winding will burn out, so you'll just do more damage.

These supply control chips are almost always victims of some other part having failed. **Burned-out parts have failed, but not all failed parts are burned out!**

Without proper tools and know-how, you won't be able to diagnose this board. You may look for a skilled electronics repair person. A few of the good ones have YouTube channels, so if you happen to be in the same area, or are willing to ship the board out for repair, there certainly are skilled people who will fix it for you for less than it'd have cost to buy a new appliance.

You can also check if this board is available as a replacement part.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I contacted an Electronist (for this client). This stove operates on a 230V Dual Line (~480V) with no need to bind to the Neutral, European grid. Also I saw the client did not bind the PE in the grid, so likely it would have stopped the damage at the resistor if it was correctly grounded.